# Loading controls from xml file

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, controls, linq-to-xml

I know how to write to xml files, but I'm having trouble doing what I need to do and can't find adequate info on this type of problem.

Here's one xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<controls>
    <Label Content="Double-click to edit." Location="258, 178" Size="101, 13" ForeColor="-1" />  
    <LinkLabel Content="Double-click to edit." Location="532, 133" Size="101, 13" LinkColor="-1" />  
    <LinkLabel Content="Double-click to edit." Location="424, 212" Size="101, 13" LinkColor="-1" /> 
    <Label Content="Double-click to edit." Location="282, 89" Size="101, 13" ForeColor="-1" />  
    <Label Content="Double-click to edit." Location="528, 178" Size="101, 13" ForeColor="-1" />  
    <LinkLabel Content="Double-click to edit." Location="528, 133" Size="101, 13" LinkColor="-1" />  
    <LinkLabel Content="Double-click to edit." Location="528, 149" Size="101, 13" LinkColor="-1" /> 
    <Label Content="Double-click to edit." Location="528, 164" Size="101, 13" ForeColor="-1" />
</controls>
```

And what I need to do once I've opened this file in my app is:

```
foreach(control in XmlFile)
{   

  get Content
  get Location
  get Size
  get ForeColor/LinkColor
  // do something...
}
```

Can somebody please help me out with this? I'd appreciate any help at all.

Thank you

Bael

Comment: I'm trying to read the xml file, and then get each "Control" in the xml file and recreate the control and place it in Panel control on the Form with the properties that are associated with that control in the xml file

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:
(For ForeColor/LinkColor check for null)

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");

            var q = from c in loaded.Descendants().Descendants()
                            select new
                            {
                                content = c.Attribute("Content"),
                                location = c.Attribute("Location"),
                                size = c.Attribute("Size"),
                                foreColor = c.Attribute("ForeColor"),
                                linkColor = c.Attribute("LinkColor")
                            };

            foreach (var controlItem in q)
                Console.WriteLine("Control content = {0}", controlItem.content);
```

Comment: thank you for this it's very nicely written. How would I also get the Name of the control? e.g. Label or LinkLabel?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to iterate on all your controls in the XML and retreive the info, you should use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx).

Here is an example:

```
XPathDocument Doc = new XPathDocument("yourfile.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = Doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("/controls/*");
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(iterator.Current.Content);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(iterator.Current.Location);
}
```